# Pythonic method to create a dictionary through iteration while also updating the values?

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a better way to create the desired output or do it in fewer lines?

```
x = ['S6', 'H12', 'S5', 'C10', 'S12', 'D13', 'H6']
dd = {"S": [], "C": [], "D": [], "H": []}
​
for z in x:
    dd[z[0:1]].append(z[1:])
    
output = {'S': ['6', '5', '12'], 'C': ['10'], 'D': ['13'], 'H': ['12', '6']}
```

Comment: Not really, you could use a default dict so you dont need to hard code `dd`'s keys when setting it up and just use `z[0]` rather than a slice but nothing performance boosting.

Comment: Note: The fewer line solutions shown below are not a "better way" from a performance or maintenance standpoint

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use defaultdic. I think that will be cleaner. You're right that they might not be "better," but I do love one-liners! :D

Comment: I find your solution already quite nice since it offers a great level of readability and you will be glad when coming back at this logic in 2 month maintaining the code in the future. The only improvement: Instead of using the slice `z[0:1]`, just use `z[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a oneliner using a some nested generators:

```
x = ['S6', 'H12', 'S5', 'C10', 'S12', 'D13', 'H6']
dd = {char : [elem[1:] for elem in x if elem[0] == char] for char in [elem[0] for elem in x]}
```

Note as well that the sliced `z[0:1]` is really just indexing using 0 (it is equivalent to `z[0]`).

Comment: Thanks! I love me some one-liners :) Always good for learning and practice.

Comment: @ChrisE Note that as mentioned in the above comments, this isn't the most performant solution, but it's nice to use with a relatively small dataset.

Comment: Yes of course. I spend too much time on Codewars creating one-liners just for fun. I love to see it.

Answer (score 1):

one option via `itertools groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
result = {g: [i[1:] for i in k] for g, k in groupby(
    sorted(x, key=lambda x: x[0]), key=lambda x: x[0])}
```

Answer (score 0):

With some regex, it can be made very short:

```
import re

x = ['S6', 'H12', 'S5', 'C10', 'S12', 'D13', 'H6']
dd = {key[0]: re.findall(f'{key[0]}(\d+)', str(x)) for key in x}
```